# Qt5 application and window icon

Tags: qt5

In my Qt5 app, I wanted to display a tiny icon in the title bar. I used

```
setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/icons/Mylogo.png"));
```

To my surprise, the icon appears (on my Ubuntu) on the sidebar, along with the other active tasks, but not in the title of the window. With the messages from my app, I also reveive

```
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
```

that may be the reason why I do not have the icon. Do I make something wrong, or do need to do something extra? (i.e. the pixmap exists, found, and used on one purpose, I guess)

Comment: The path `:/...` is interpreted by a `QFileEngine` that uses the Qt resource system to access the data. The image must be compiled as a binary object into the executable. Have you declared that icon as a Qt resource? Read up on Qt Resource System if you didn't.

Comment: As I mentioned, the icon is read from the resource and correctly displayed. I.e the single like make two actions: once displays and icon, and second gives an error message thet the pixmap is null.

Answer (score 0):

No minimum example and no info about window manager.. my advice is to look into platform notes for [Setting the Application Icon](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/appicon.html)

Your icon may be under control of e.g. KDE/GNOME theme.